# jquery mmenu: is it possible to have different button size in clone?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I have 2 versions of the menu:

- $menu = on-canvas menu for widescreen
- $menu-mobile = off-canvas menu for tablets and phones

With media-queries I can switch between the two. Took some time to figure out how to get the properties right, but works like a charm!
However, now I run into some styling problems: 
With Sass I created a custom-menu.css that makes the button-size 30px instead of default 40px as this looks better with the layout of the (widescreen) page.
But the buttons in the off-canvas menu are now also 30px heigh and that is not very comfortable on phones. There seems to be only one variable that influences the height: $mm_btnSize but that also changes the size of the cloned menu.

So is there a way to set the button height of the cloned menu separately? The arguments of mm-sizing only deals with size or widths...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the button in media-queries so that they are different for widescreen and mobile. Assuming that you are going from widescreen to mobile for your media-queries, you would go.

```
button-size {
  height: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  button-size {
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

Please note that this is pure CSS though, I'm assuming you know how to use media queries with SASS

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - or I must be doing something wrong with generating the stylesheet with SASS. Can you please give an example of how to add this media-query in a custom.mmenu.scss?